# How to use an array as function argument

Tags: objective-c, c

I try to understand how to use an array as an argument for a function.

I have an error when i put arguments in this way :minimum([5],10). It is obvious wrong , but I don't know how to make it right.

My example is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int minimum(int values[],int numElements)
{
    int minValue,i;
    minValue = values[0];

    for(i=1;i < numElements; ++i)
       if(values[i] < minValue)
           minValue = values[i];

    return(minValue);
}

main()
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int result;
        NSLog(@"For values 5 and numElements 10 results minValue  %i", minimum([5],10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What is `[5]` supposed to represent?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this at all (as an Objective-C question)? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: This is really more a C question than an Objective-C question.

Comment: I try to pass arguments for my function but i don't know how because one of the argument is an array

Comment: I suggest you start with a good [language reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays).

Comment: Well, create an Array and pass it. It's a regular C array btw, nothing specific to Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to check the minimum value of the first 5 values in an `array[10]`? in C you can do it in this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimum(int values[], int numElements) /* or simply int *values */
{
    int minValue,i;

    minValue = values[0];
    for(i=1;i < numElements; ++i) /* do you mean i = 0? */
       if(values[i] < minValue)
           minValue = values[i];

    return(minValue);
}

main() /* int main(void) */
{
    int result[10] = {7, 4, 5, 8, 1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 6};

    printf("%d\n", minimum(result, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass using its name and which member.

```
printf("at 0=%d at 5=%d", functionname(array), functionname(&array[5]));
```

You need to supply the location (address) of the array item. If you use just the name, it's the same as writing &array[0] (address of 0th member of the array). Otherwise, &array[ member ] will create an address that starts with that member.